# How to calculate Total CPU Requests for a Node

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana, metrics, promql

```
kubectl describe node node-name
```

gives us a summary of cpu requests and limits

```
Resource           Requests              Limits
--------           --------              ------
cpu                3449m (98%)           20700m (591%)
                           ↑
```

Im trying to get the CPU Requests % from Prometheus Metrics with PromQL in Grafana

I can get the CPU requests Total and sum it by node with

```
sum by (node) (kube_pod_container_resource_requests_cpu_cores)
```

not sure how to plug `kube_node_status_allocatable_cpu_cores` here which gives me allocatable cpu for each node. Note all my nodes have the some number of cores.

How to mix node and container metrics in one query?

Comment: I don't understand. Do you mean, the total CPU requests for pods which happened to be scheduled on a node? You'll probably need to join another metric which has both the container names and the node label.